# Capybara + RSpec only sees blank pages in controller specs. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a controller spec for a simple controller. However, Capybara isn't seeing any page content. However, looking at the site's pages in my browser works just fine. What am I doing wrong?

T. Hanks!

[My controller spec](https://gist.github.com/962067)

[My spec_helper.rb](https://gist.github.com/962065)

[My Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/962064)

Comment: Have you tried it without Spork? That might be causing problems.

Comment: Removing Spork does not change anything, it seems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell your controller spec that you want it to render views in order for this to work. Update your spec to look like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PostsController do
  render_views # Render this controller's views during spec execution.

  before do
    @post = Fabricate :post
  end

  # ...
end
```

This is described in rspec's [readme](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails). For a more detailed view, see rspec-rails' cucumber [feature for 'render_views'](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/features/controller_specs/render_views.feature).

Just one word of caution with this. There are reasons why this isn't default behaviour:

- Arguably, you're mixing two concerns by testing the views at the same time as the controllers. Ryan Bigg (see comments) suggests your tests *might* be better thought of as integration tests, which usually live in `spec/integration` rather than `spec/controller`.
- Rendering the views may slow down the execution of your tests considerably.

... Not saying you shouldn't do this, just saying you should be clear *why you are*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would advise that the OP doesn't use controller tests for this, but rather creates new tests in `spec/integration` for these. Controller tests test *single* actions, integration tests the whole stack.

Comment: Agreed - hence my comment about mixing concerns. You've articulated it much better than I did, however. I'll incorporate your comment into the answer.

Comment: The cucumber-generated docs are also published: http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/dir/controller-specs/render-views, http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/dir/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default

Comment: Thanks, guys. This fixed it, but don't worry. I'm separating my tests into controller and integration this time. TDD is kind of confusing, when you're starting out.

Comment: The Capybara convention is to put these in spec/requests, no? why spec/integration instead?