# Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I testing with rspec, Im still learning, I guess I'm on the right way... but when I test my rspec file I got this error:

```
 Failures:

1) UsersController signup with valid information should create a user
 Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/user_controller_spec.rb:31

Finished in 1.16 seconds
```

2 examples, 1 failures

I know what this mean, but I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me with this trouble please...Also I put my rspec file

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do


describe "signup" do

before { visit new_user_registration_path }

let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

describe "with invalid information" do
  it "should not create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
  end
end

describe "with valid information" do
  before do
    fill_in "Email", :with=> "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with=> "foobar"
    #fill_in "password_confirmation", :with=> "foobar"
  end
```

(here is that the error appears...below line)

```
      it "should create a user" do
         expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
   end
  end
end
```

thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a failing spec. The spec itself looks ok. So I would check on

- is the implementation in place? You can try out the scenario in your browser. Does it work there? If not, you have a failing test (which is good) and need to add the implementation.
- if the implementation works, check the spec again carefully. Is the provided information

  fill_in "Email", :with=> "user@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with=> "foobar"

  sufficient to create a user?
- if you still haven't found the cause, you could use capybaras save_and_open_page (install launchy gem for that) and peek at the page during your test.

ADDITION:

ok, as I said, this should be an integration test - move it from the spec/controllers to the spec/requests folder (and do change the first line, as you're not describing the UsersController! but that should not lead to the problem).

Comment: ps: if you have trouble investigating, please post the actual failure from rspec (further up in the output) - and another thing I've noticed: is this an integration or an controller test? (where is it located?) - from the file I would say an integration test, but it says describe UsersController. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932605/capybara-rspec-only-sees-blank-pages-in-controller-specs-why for a discussion on that.

Comment: thanks for answer, reading your post, I guess the spec is insufficient because the implementation works

Comment: could you post the complete output of the failing spec then?

Comment: which framework are you using? webrat or capybara? I've just moved my very similar integration test to the controllers folder and got very different error messages: 
6) User pages signup with invalid information after submission 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fa7cd8b2550>
     # ./spec/controllers/user_pages_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Im using capybara, that error appeared before install capybara but not now

Comment: That's strange. but still, have you just tried to move it to the requests folder? and used save_and_open_page?

Comment: mmm no but why I have to move to the request folder??'

Comment: because in capybara controller specs the views are not rendered, as explained in detail in the link I've posted above.