# Why I get blank pages when using selenium/webkit with capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to test my cucumber scenarios with capybara and selenium but I get blank pages all the time.

I read this: [Capybara + RSpec only sees blank pages in controller specs. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932605/capybara-rspec-only-sees-blank-pages-in-controller-specs-why)

But It's not exactly the same because that is with rspec.

My env.rb has:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
```

I have try to change it to :selenium but it's the same story.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use these drivers only for javascript, do you really need them as default driver?
Do you want to always use them?

It could just be a timeout issue..

If you want to set them for JavaScript only do this instead (env.rb):

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

And decorate your scenarios with @javascript as such:

```
@javascript
Scenario: Customers List
```